# Portable webserver - cross platform

Tags: cross-platform, web-server, portable

I want a portable web server which works in Windows, Linux, Mac i.e cross platform which can be carried in a pen drive. I want to serve website content with search, which is portable in usb drive and works offline.

As long as we can share it with anyone, the paid software may cost max of 200$.